# Conversion from signed int to signed char?

Tags: c++

I'm following an example from Stroustrups C_++ 4th Ed. Page 143, where there is Errata.  -160, should be -140.

Specifically the conversion of a signed int to a signed char.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
    signed char sc = -140;
    cout << "signed int = " <<
    int((signed int) (0b11111111111111111111111101110100))
          << endl; // -140, 4 bytes
    cout << "signed int & 0xFF = " << int((signed int) -140 & 0xFF)
          << endl; // 116, narrow 2 bytes    
    unsigned char uc = sc; // 256 - 140 = 116
    return 0;
}
```

I understand how the conversion is a narrowing of 4 bytes, to 2 bytes which result in -140 being converted to 116.  I am confused on the comment Stroustrup adds for the line `unsigned char uc = sc` where it is `// 256 - 140 = 116`.  I see it results in the correct answer 116, but am unsure how that conversion is done.  I'm aware that an unsigned char max limit completely full of 1's is 255 or 2^8 - 1.  Does anyone know why this math in the comment works?

UPDATE:
The solution is -140 mod 256 = 116.

Thanks

Comment: `-140` is outside the range of a char. "Working" in C++ is undefined behavior, but it involves however the compiler developer decided to  handle underflowing.

Comment: @Taekahn that you! very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting a value to an `unsigned` type, the value is taken *modulo N*,
where `N = 2sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT`.

In simple terms, it means that `N*i` is added to the value to put it in the  representable range, where `i` is an integer (possibly negative).

You can always determine a single specific value of `i` that puts the value into the representable range. In your case, `i = 1`, so, `256 * 1` is added to the value.

Comment: I'm asking about the comment 256 - 140 = 116 math.  What is CHAR_BIT?  Still confused by your answer

Comment: @notaorb [`CHAR_BIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) is a constant equal to the amount of bits in a byte, on most platforms it's `8`. *"asking about the comment 256 - 140 = 116"* Yep, and I think my answer explains it. `256 - 140` is equal to `-140 + 256*1`, where `256` is `N` and `1` is `i`.

Comment: 256 is zero mod 256. So mod 256, -140 is equal to (-140 + 256). (-140 + 256) is equal to (256 + -140) which is equal to 256-140. So, mod 256, -140 is equal to 116. (Also, any two numbers that are 256 apart are equal mod 256. -140 and 116 are 256 apart.)

Comment: Ok, so per this post the answer is taken V mod N, i.e. -140 mod 256 = 116.  Understood.  My questions are why is 256 chosen when the max value for uint_8 is 255.  I think that's where I'm lost.

Comment: @notaorb "mod N" can only give you values in range 0..N-1. So if the max value is 255, the N needs to be 1 larger.

Answer (score 1):

Two byte `int` hasn't been common for a long time now; most `int` are 4 bytes.

Regardless, it's the top bit that matters for a signed number.  The expression `-140 & 0xff` results in `0b01110100`  which is 116, because all those sign bits get chopped off.

To make it even simpler, let's look at the full bit patterns.

```
-140 = 0b11111111111111111111111101110100 (first sign bit is set)
0xff = 0b00000000000000000000000011111111 (bottom 8 bits set, all others zero)
&    : 0b00000000000000000000000001110100 = 116
```

Comment: I already stated that.  I'm asking why the answer in the comment is 256 - 140 = 116

Comment: @notaorb and I explained it, I thought the explanation was adequate.  All you need to do is look at the bit pattern.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the bit pattern and chopping off as demonstrated in the code.  I'm confused where 256 comes from, as a unsigned char can represent 2^8 - 1 = 255.

Comment: @notaorb 256 is just an artifact of using two's complement arithmetic for negative numbers, and is totally irrelevant.  Look at my updated answer.

Comment: @notaorb Here's another way to think about it. `256` is `1 0000 0000` in binary, so adding or subtracting it lets you manipulate upper n-8 bits without affecting the lower 8 bits.